# How to kill SparkR job

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I am using Spark 2.0.0 and I have web based RStudio through which I am using SparkR package.

While running a large program if I have to kill a job during process, How can I do that?

STOP button in R doesn't work and If I kill the session itself then all the objects created in that session also get removed.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since R probably blocks because it is waiting for a response from Spark, the most suitable way might be to access the WebUI (if it is accessible of course) and kill the current Stage.

Open up the **master** WebUI (default port is 8080) and click on **SparkR**, which is the application name.
[image: Spark Master WebUI]
Now you are in the **SparkR application UI**. Click on **Stages** and kill the active stage by pressing on **(kill)**. This of course doesn't kill everything, only the active stage and other stages might also needed to be killed.
[image: Spark Application WebUI]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write: 
sparkR.session.stop()

Then restart session of R:

Session -> Restart R